# TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE was not declared in this scope, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi

`windows.h` is included, code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  HANDLE hToken;
  DWORD dwSize;
  TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE pElevationType = TokenElevationTypeDefault;
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
  GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevationType, pElevationType, sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE), &dwSize)
}
```

Compiler is MinGW 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively recent addition to the relevant enumeration in the Windows API, and perhaps you don't have the required Platform SDK level present - confirm where `winnt.h` is being picked up from, and track down the right Platform SDK if this value is missing in yours.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530718(v=vs.85).aspx

> Requirements
>
> Minimum supported client
> Windows Vista
>
> Minimum supported server
> Windows Server 2008
>
> Header
> Winnt.h

The Windows SDK for WSrv 2008 is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310).